# Subtraction in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, sense

I have created query in elastic search to get more then two file with same name and hash.The query is -

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggregations": {
    "server": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "owner"
      },
      "aggregations": {
        "md5hash": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "md5hash"
          },
          "aggregations": {
            "sFileName": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "sFileName",
                "min_doc_count": 2
              },
              "aggregations": {
                "sourcesum": {
                  "sum": {
                    "field": "sourceSize"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now I want to subtract doc.["sourceSize"] from sourcesum. How can I do this in above query.

Comment: how would you do this subtraction, sourceSize comes from each document and sourcesum is aggregation. Don't sum up to something, can you put some pseduo query you trying to achieve?

Comment: @user3775217 I sum up the duplicate records source size, so all the records have same source size and I want to subtract any one of the source size

Answer (score 0):

You can do so by using the scripted metric aggregation

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-scripted-metric-aggregation.html

Here you can subtract the sourceSize and then perform the aggregation.

Comment: can u suggest how to implement scripted metric aggregation in my query